# Why Mathematica gaves two different results?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I asked Mathematica to do a very simple volume finding integration exercise for me. I tried on two different approaches, one on Cartesian and the other on Polar coordinates, however, it gives me two different results. Anybody can tell me why?

[image]

Comment: Please provide in Mathematica format (not images) the code you actually used.

Comment: The code I used were like these:
Clear[a, m];
Integrate[ 1, {y, -a/3, a/3}, {x, 0, Sqrt[a^2 - 9 y^2]}, {z, 0, m x}]
/*...........*/
Clear[a, m];
Integrate[
 a/Sqrt[Cos[ \[Theta]]^2 + 9 Sin[ \[Theta]]^2], {r, 0, 
  a}, {\[Theta], -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {z, 0, 
  m  Cos[\[Theta]]/Sqrt[Cos[ \[Theta]]^2 + 9 Sin[ \[Theta]]^2]}]

Comment: You should be editing these into your question instead of leaving them as a comment.

Comment: You have over 2k rep, been a member for almost 3 years, asked 44 questions, and throw your codes in a comment? How is that even possible...?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the domain:

```
A = ImplicitRegion[x^2 + 9 y^2 <= a^2 && 0 <= z <= m x, {x, y, z}];
```

its measure is easily calculable as:

```
Assuming[a > 0 && m > 0, Integrate[1, {x, y, z} \[Element] A]]
```

or equivalently as:

```
Integrate[1, {y, -a/3, a/3}, {x, 0, Sqrt[a^2 - 9 y^2]}, {z, 0, m x}]
```

or as:

```
Integrate[r/3, {r, 0, a}, {t, -Pi/2, Pi/2}, {z, 0, m r Cos[t]}]
```

That's all.

---

Wishing to hurt, you can also refer to the polar coordinates in space:

```
Integrate[r^2/3 Sin[f], 
          {f, 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[m^2 + 1] - m], Pi/2},
          {t, -ArcCos[Cot[f]/m], ArcCos[Cot[f]/m]}, 
          {r, 0, a/Sin[f]}
         ]
```

that because of the complexity of the calculations it is good to be calculated as follows:

```
V[f_] = Integrate[r^2/3 Sin[f], 
                   f, 
                  {t, -ArcCos[Cot[f]/m], ArcCos[Cot[f]/m]}, 
                  {r, 0, a/Sin[f]}
                 ];
Limit[V[f], f -> Pi/2] - Limit[V[f], f -> 2 ArcTan[Sqrt[m^2 + 1] - m]]
```

Comment: Hi Manu, Thank you for your answers. Sorry I don't follow why use r/3 as the integrand in your last statement. Could you please explain a bit further?

Comment: Hi Manu, Oh yes, I see, you transform the ellipse into a circle, like x = a u, y = a v /3,  and obtain the Jacobian as \[PartialD](x, y)/\[PartialD](u, v) = a^2/3 then doing the integration in a perfect cylindrical coord. But my question is how this problem be solved on polar coord?

Comment: Hi Manu, Thanks, yes you are right.

Answer (score 0):

I finally noticed the mistake I made, I substitute the value into the variable r too early, I should let Mathematica do it.

`Integrate[r, 
 {\[Theta], -(Pi/2), Pi/2}, 
  {r, 0, a/Sqrt[9*Sin[\[Theta]]^2 + Cos[\[Theta]]^2]},
 {z, 0, (m*r*Cos[\[Theta]])}]`

[image]

Comment: Lot of thanks to the nice guys there on Mathematic StackExchange :
[link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2214947/how-to-find-a-volume-in-polar-coordinate-system)